# Как вытащить строку из системных mui файлов?

Tags: winapi

Мне нужно использовать строку из системных ресурсов которые находятся в c:\windows\system32 и имеют расширение *mui. Например poqexec.exe.mui. Программа Resource hacker выдаёт такую структуру

```
1 MESSAGETABLE
{
0x40000001,     "Обновление системы... (%5!Iu!%%)%r%0\r\n"
0xC0000002,     "Ошибка %4!lX! при операции обновления %1!Iu! из %2!Iu! (%3)%r%0\r\n"
0xC0000003,     "Неустранимая ошибка %4!lX! при операции обновл. %1!Iu! из %2!Iu! (%3)%r%0\r\n"
}
```

Как мне вытащить строку по адресу 0x40000001 и использовать в дальнейшем в моей программе?

Пробую что-то типа этого:

```
HMODULE resContainer = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\ru-RU\\poqexec.exe.mui");
HRSRC myResource= FindResource(resContainer, MAKEINTRESOURCE(0x40000001), RT_MESSAGETABLE);
HGLOBAL myResourceData = LoadResource(resContainer, myResource);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть функция [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx). Ваше приложение должно иметь ту же архитектуру (32бит или 64бит), что и DLL.

```
HMODULE resContainer = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\ru-RU\\poqexec.exe.mui");

LPTSTR pBuffer;   // Buffer to hold the textual error description.
if (FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | // Function will handle memory allocation.
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE | // Using a module's message table.
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    resContainer, // Handle to the DLL.
    0x40000001, // Message identifier.
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language.
    (LPTSTR)&pBuffer, // Buffer that will hold the text string.
    256, // Allocate at least this many chars for pBuffer.
    NULL // No insert values.
    )) 
{
    MessageBox(0, pBuffer, 0, 0);
    LocalFree(pBuffer);
}
```